# Using uBlock Origin, how do I block a root site without blocking sub-pages?

Tags: ublock-origin

I am getting really distracted by YouTube recently, but I still need access to YouTube videos. I inadvertently visit youtube.com, and I would like to block this page without blocking the whole site. Is there a uBlock filter that only works on the root page?

Comment: So you want to only block YT frontpage "youtube.com" and be able to access all other YT pages? It appears that the given `||youtube.com^$document` filter blocks youtube.com completely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a [uBlock Origin] filter that only works on the root page?

Yes, use the `document` filter option:

```
||youtube.com^|$document
```

Comment: With this filter, YouTube videos embedded on other websites played normally as expected. However, it's worth noting that the video page itself will still be blocked.

Comment: I've understood that he only wants to block a single page, youtube.com. The filter blocks youtube.com completely.

Comment: You're both right, I misread. I corrected my answer (added trailing `|`).

Comment: Doesn't really work. Yes, first visit will block it, however, when you go to a site that has an embedded youtube video, click on it to open it in Youtube and in Youtube click the home button brings you to the root page...

Answer (score 0):

With [Squid Cache Rule](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl) (see [Why Squid](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/WhySquid)):

```
acl whitedomains dstdomain -i "/path_to_acl/whitedomains.txt"
acl blackdomains dstdomain -i "/path_to_acl/blackdomains.txt"
http_access allow whitedomains
http_access deny blackdomains
```

Content of the lists:

```
/path_to_acl/whitedomains.txt
.account.youtube.com
.google.com

/path_to_acl/blackdomains.txt
.youtube.com
.googlevideo.com
.ytimg.com
```

PD: [Since February 2014, Google uses the accounts subdomain .youtube.com to authenticate their services](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Streams/YouTube).

Source: [Blackweb Project](https://github.com/maravento/blackweb)